Celery Chord is not responding or receiving feedback from all tasks when a Kubernetes pod is redeployed
I have implemented a pipeline that uses Celery's chord to track, on average, 7,000 Celery tasks. Based on their callback status, the pipeline determines whether to call a fallback function, depending on the success rate.
The issue arises when tasks are running, and in the middle of the process, a redeployment occurs. When this happens, the chord fails to accurately calculate the task statuses, which prevents the fallback from being called if the majority of tasks fail.
How can I resolve this issue?
